# REST app with Jersey 2 ClassNotFoundException : com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

where jersey.version=2.5.

I use the embedded jetty (maven-jetty-plugin) to start the REST application. When mvn jetty:run is executed, the following exception occurs.

```
2015-10-21 00:21:32.883:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2015-10-21 00:21:33.478:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@782a4fff{/promat,C:\wses\promat\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
...
...
```

So long as I was using 1.8 dependency for jersey - there was no issue. 
This is the dependency for which there was no issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

What is the missing artifact? Jersey-server with 1.8 had ServletContainer class.

Comment: You don't need any other dependencies. Though @MatthewMadson answer is correct. I imagine it may not completely solve the problem. My guess is you are using all Jersey 1.x configuration in your web.xml.

Comment: For help migrating I suggest you post your web.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the class has been moved to:

[org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.5/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html)

Though I haven't verified if they have the same semantics, so there may be additional migration steps necessary.